# Angular Tutorial: Tour of Heroes lesson 2: data binding to hero from selectedHero

Tags: angular, angular2-databinding

In Angular tutorial lesson 2 on https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview

I can see in HeroComponent template, [(ngModel)] is 2-way binding the selectedHero.name as the input value changes. How come it's binding and changing {{hero.name}} 1-way interpolation on the heroes list above at the same time? Should have made sense if it was {{selectedHero.name}} interpolation on the list, right?

Can someone please explain to me what basic logic I'm missing out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question: 
`onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
}`

with this instruction the `hero: Hero` is a pointer to the Element of type Hero.

`this.selectedHero = hero` is giving the same pointer to `selectedHero`, so they are 2 pointers to the same obj. This is why on the change of value they are changing both.

Comment: Brilliant! My idea of it was, (click) event was just passing hero argument and assigning it to another entity selectedHero (effectively another pointer) of same type. However, what would have been different in the code if I wanted to keep the list unchanged as I change the input and its <h2> header. Thanks!

Comment: if they were two different entities you would be right. Remembre that if you would have ANOTHER reference to the object and not to his pointer you should have done this: `onSelect(hero: Hero): void { this.selectedHero = new Hero();
      Object.assign(this.selectedHero, hero); }` You're welcome, just ask you to vote my answer ;)

Comment: It's much clear now. As I'm new (under 15 reputation), my vote cast is recorded but not changing publicly. I will come back and vote once I reach this threshold.